# Responsive layout without media query

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm looking for a creative way of doing responsive layout without media query.

Let's say I have a row of two boxes. First one has min width of 400px. Second one has min width of 200px. The gap between them is fixed width 60px.

If the container is larger than 660px, then two boxes should expand proportionally. If the container is less than 660px, then the second box should go to next line, and both boxes' widths should be 100%.

I almost got it with css flexbox. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5wkxu9b9/9/). Except that when the container is less than 660px, the first box's width doesn't expand to 100% (because of fixed `margin-right: 60px`).

I know it's easy to achieve with media query or some css frameworks like bootstrap, but I want to see if it's possible without media query.

I've been looking into **flexbox** and **css grid** for such possibility but no success. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The reason behind this is that I want to build a responsive layout based on the container's width, not viewport's width. **Element Query** solves this but it's not implemented in major browsers yet.

Comment: This is like trying to take a picture without a camera. Or flying without a plane. Responsiveness and media queries are inextricably linked in a way that even the most devious of W3C schemers can never untangle.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a media query? That's what it's for.

Comment: is there any issue to using media query?

Comment: you can use `flexbox` I guess but you need to work around your calculations more.
maybe something like this https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/EKEYob

Comment: See my edit for why I don't want media query.

Comment: see CSS grid and pay close attention to `auto` vs `fr` units and `grid-gap` for your 60px gap.

Comment: For those who think it's impossible, check out the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if you wrap the boxes in a new container and give this container a style with the margin of the boxes inside as a negative value. See https://jsfiddle.net/qnop1wb8/9/

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper__body {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 -30px;
  display: inherit;
  flex-wrap: inherit;
}

[class*="box"] {
  margin: 0 30px;
}

.box1 {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.box2 {
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="wrapper__body">

<div class="box1">

</div>
<div class="box2">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually you don't need two wrappers to make it work. One wrapper is enough. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qnop1wb8/14/). But your solution works!!!

Comment: That's correct, but you may get overflows.  So I would suggest to use the body as well so you could set overflow: hidden; on the "actual" parent (.wrapper in this case). This has advantages if your placing it in nested layouts with paddings or margins.

Comment: You are right, but the actual parent wouldn't need `display: flex` and `flex-wrap`, right?

Answer (score 1):

`display: grid` and `grid-template-colums: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1f))`

beautiful video Jen Simmoons

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFKrK4eAiUQ

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use css media queries, javascript is the only option with the resize event:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    if(window.innerWidth > 1000){
        // do something if window is bigger than 1000px
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
});
```